# Double scrollbar in First Posts Queue

Tags: bug, design, review-queues

When reviewing first posts I noticed there are two scrollbars:

[image]

---

[image]

Here are links to some reviews that I saw this on:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/303268
- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/303259
- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/303519
- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/303618 (answer)

I saw it happen on some posts both before and after the post was reviewed, but (because I think it's caused by the new user indicator) it goes away after a week. The bug is not fixed because I'm seeing it on [new reviews](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/304754). However, I'm still using the old navigation (i.e. no left sidebar).

This is completely unnecessary, as there's not even anything further down when you scroll the inner one. In any case, the correct behavior is to only have one of the scroll bars (i.e. the outer one which scrolls the entire page).

I also noticed [one review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/303395) that has a double scrollbar and a single horizontal one. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTkE0.png) is a screenshot. This is also pointless and annoying.

Furthermore, I have now spotted this very same thing on a [page outside the queue](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/466880/191178) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcYoe.png)).

I just checked some other sites (Stack Overflow, ELL, Skeptics) and I didn't see this happening. And I don't think I see it happening on all posts in that queue either.

I've checked some other metas and saw that people have also reported this bug on:

- [UX](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3284/83293)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1576)

I'd like to see this fixed. My setup here is Chrome on Mac (on the "old" site design). Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: I'm seeing it. In fact your second example has both a horizontal and a vertical scrollbar around it on my browser, in addition to the scrollbar for the entire page.

Comment: Scrollbarception!

Comment: [Also happened on UX.SE](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3284/56950)

Comment: The two scrollbars also show up on Firefox 61.0.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @JJJ It seems to be linked to the new user indicator, so all of the examples I had originally no longer show it. However, I still see it on new reviews like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/304754).

Comment: Someone will berate me, no doubt, but in my experience, bugs are best reported on Stack Exchange meta. Usually, you get a much quicker response there. On the other hand, SE developers etc. could be ignoring this defect because the new theme is imminent and they probably feel it's a waste of time fixing something that will soon no longer exist.

Comment: Retracted upvote, the issue on EL&U will not be resolved for the reason I explained above.